# Meaning of '沒梗'?

Tags: meaning

> 你為什麼打我？ 是沒梗了嗎？

I'm wondering what 沒梗 means in this context. I know the literal translation is  'no stem', but I'm sure there should be an idiomatic meaning to it.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in @songyuanyao's answer, `梗` is a common typo of the word `哏`. In fact, you can barely find the correct usage `哏` in some Chinese-speaking communities.

The word originally meant `funny, amusing`, but then, as @songyuanyao mentioned, it became a technical term in `相聲`. To help you understand better, `相聲` are most similar to standup comedies in English, except it's usually played by two people. `哏` can be understood as a joke that is often implicitly presented in a speech. Note that the joke here can refer to as a particular word or phrase that is only humorous in a certain context as well as a standalone joke.

As to your example, the second sentence can be translated to `are you out of jokes?`. A possible instance of your example would be:

> Ａ：「你每次都打人，有沒有什麼新招啊？」
>   Ｂ打Ａ
>   Ａ：「你為什麼打我？ 是沒梗了嗎？」
>   "You always hit others, can you do any better?"
>   B hits A.
>   "What? You out of jokes? Is that the best you got?"

Comment: Ahhh, I understand now. Thank you both so much!

Answer (score 4):

`梗`, the point ( of joke ), `没梗` means `There's no points, not funny`.

BTW: `梗` is a wrongly used word, even it's widely used nowadays (especially at Taiwan). It should be `哏`, which often used for [相声](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/786/4072), means the funny thing, the punch line, the point of laugh.

Reference:http://tieba.baidu.com/p/1439412199

Comment: So the second sentence could be translated as 'Is it not funny?' (in response to the person hitting him)?

Comment: I think it could be translated as `Don't you have any other funny things to do?`.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the popularity of banter style conversations. You can understand 梗 as materials or punch lines. More generalised, it could mean an effective response.

So a more natural translation for 没梗 would be along the line of "out of stuff".

The full sentence would be:

"Why did you hit me! Are you out of stuff!"

For example, in a confrontational conversation, parties are supposed to battle with each other with their debate skills. However when on party that is out of stuff and cannot come up with an effective response, the party may escalate the situation to physical confrontation which is considered stupid. By the way, I'm not taking about this as a Chinese culture thing, it's universal human behavior.

**Banter**

Now, in the bullshitting (扯淡) part of our modern Chinese culture, an interactive bullshitting conversation session should be refreshing, interesting and enjoyable. Each party is supposed to bring up something interesting, novel or clever, otherwise the bullshit is just bullshit. Now more and more day to day conversations are adopting this style, especially among close friends and online.